# Overriding the VS2010 Project Invalidated (refreshed) event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vspackage

I'm trying to override VS2010 behaviour when an external program makes changes to the project or solution files. Atm VS throws a popup asking if you want to reload/save the project files.

I've trying to override this behaviour however I have yet to find a solution. Is there some way to override the event or programatically set VS so it automatically lets external changes refresh active projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some configuration options available at

```
Menu Tools - Options - Environment - Documents
```

Look at the checkbox and other options

```
Detect when file is changed outside the environment
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. Would you happen to know how to do this programatically and override the event so I can run my own code?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not aware of any direct method to receive this kind of notification. Perhaps you could search on the MSDN about [Automation and Extensibility of Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc52cke4.aspx)